# Checking out maven project error. "handshake alert: unrecognized_name"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn

trying to check out maven project gives me `handshake alert: unrecognized_name` googled it with no luck. adding `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` to `eclipse.ini` does not work. tried using java 1.7 / 1.8 ,,, svn connector 1.7/1.8. just nothing ! 
anyhow its supposed to ask me for username and password, but it does not , just gives me the error screen below. please help!

[image]

Comment: Does the checkout on the command line work? Is it a problem with the remote repository, the local client, your settings or something else?

Comment: pretty sure its the settings ,, was working fine on windows 7, eclipse Indigo, JavaHL 1.8 connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that problem as well ,its caused by the SVN connector, i didn't find a solution but you should use JavaHL connector, which for some reason doesn't work on Linux.